# Cannot access a disposed object when injecting DbContext through Azure Function

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I am receiving the following error when trying to inject the DbContext into an Azure Function:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

Here is the current function

```
    private readonly FundCentreContext _fundCentreContext;

    public GetDailyPrices(FundCentreContext fundCentreContext)
    {
        _fundCentreContext = fundCentreContext;
    }
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [FunctionName(nameof(GetDailyPrices))]
    public IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "api/dailyprices")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {

        //Parameters
        var parameters = req.GetQueryParameterDictionary();

        var page = int.Parse(parameters.GetValueOrDefault("page", "0"));
        var limit = int.Parse(parameters.GetValueOrDefault("limit", "10"));
        var offset = int.Parse(parameters.GetValueOrDefault("offset", "0"));
        var sort = parameters.GetValueOrDefault("sort", "asc");

        var fundService = new FundService(_fundCentreContext);

        var fundDailyPrices = fundService.GetAllDailyPricesByPage(page, limit, offset);

        return fundDailyPrices != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(fundDailyPrices)
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("There was an error with your request");
    }
```

And also the StartUp to use the service has the following code:

```
services
    .AddDbContext<FundCentreContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer("*ommited*"));
```

I can't work out why this error is occuring - debugging past the return statement works, and data can be seen in the fundDailyPrices object, however something after the return statement ends the whole function unexpectedly.

Comment: Is your `GetAllDailyPricesByPage` function is `async`?

Comment: Why using `async Task` if nothing is being awaited?

Comment: It was my intention to add await to GetAllDailyPricesByPage() function, but currently it's not asynchronous anyway. I've edited question and removed async to remove confusion. The error still occurs with a synchronous function.

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242457/timertrigger-does-not-inject-ef-database-context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell with the code you've provided, but the most likely culprit is that you aren't materializing the result set until the context has gone out of scope. Again, we can't see all the code, but this happens when you do things like return an `IQueryable` directly. Any type of service call should return a materialized list (i.e. call `ToList()` or `ToListAsync()` on the result set before returning). It might also be caused by lazy-loading, if you've enabled that feature. If so, yo should make sure that all necessary relationships are eagerly loaded.

It's also weird that you're newing up your service with an injected context. You should simply inject your service, and since it has a constructor dependency on your context, that will be automatically injected into it. That ensures that both objects are operating in the same, or at least compatible, lifetime.

Also, don't use `IDisposable` with injected dependencies. We can't tell anything about your service class, but if it does implement `IDisposable`, remove that.

Comment: Isn't it pretty standard to inject DbContext with EF?  I'm not certain why in particular you wouldn't inject something disposable.

Comment: You're conflating different things. The issue here was not injecting the service, not the context. Of course the context should be injected, but when using DI, everything up and down the chain should be injected. The second issue is implement IDisposable on a service class, assuming it doesn't own any dependencies. The context is being injected, so the service class should absolutely not dispose the context because it doesn't own it.