# Azure Time-based function does not trigger after publish

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-functions

I have developed many Http Triggered functions in span of 10 years (.NET Framework). I love them.
I have also developed some Timer Triggered Azure functions.

From last 15 days I am struggling with stupid issue that I can not find the solution.

I developed complete Azure function (.NET 6) and published to Azure it never invoke on time (5 minute). Struggled troubleshooting with different experiments.

Here I have simple case for you to understand.

I broke down things into simple steps. Started from scratch

I created an Azure function (timer based) from the portal, it invokes after every 5 minutes.
I downloaded publish profile, created an Azure function in C# .NET6/7 (without any change) I published to portal. It invokes after 5 minutes.

When I installed Entity Framework Nuget package, No change in code, published the function. It does not invoke Azure function (ever).

All the time, interval is set to `"0 */5 * * * *"`

> Additional Info : I do not want to create function Logging In Azure
> from Visual studio

Have you ever faced this issue before? What would you suggest me to try?

Here is code snippet of my function

```
public class LateNotice
    {
        [FunctionName("LateNotice")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this answer helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242457/timertrigger-does-not-inject-ef-database-context

Comment: my function has non-static run method already

Comment: @Ishrar could you share Entity Framework details also?

Comment: @Ishrar sharing the code that I tried with Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this reference for Entity Framework on Azure Functions with Dependency Injection in [Time trigger](https://medium.com/globant/entity-framework-on-azure-functions-with-dependency-injection-77208c94a16). Thank @  [Kunal Borkar](https://github.com/kunalborker/AzureFunctionWithEF).

[image]

**Code:**

```cs
    public class MyTimerFunction
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext dbContext;

        public MyTimerFunction(MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [FunctionName("MyTimerFunction")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * 5"
#if DEBUG
            , RunOnStartup = true
#endif
        )] TimerInfo myTimer, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                
                var csv = GetCSVDetails.GetCSVContent(Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Resources", "new_user_credentials.csv"));
                if (csv != null)
                {
                    foreach (var line in csv)
                    {
                        var username = line.Username;

                        // Check if a record with the same username already exists
                        var existingRecord = dbContext.Test.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);

                        if (existingRecord != null)
                        {
                           
                            log.LogInformation($"Updated existing record for Username: {username}");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            var test = new Data
                            {
                                Username = username,
                                Password = line.Password,
                                AccesskeyID = line.AccesskeyID,
                                Secretaccesskey = line.Secretaccesskey,
                                Consoleloginlink = line.Consoleloginlink
                            };

                            dbContext.Test.Add(test);
                        }
                    }

                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    log.LogWarning(" data is null or invalid.");
                }

                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.LogCritical(e.Message);
                log.LogCritical(e.StackTrace);

                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    log.LogCritical("Inner Exception: " + e.InnerException.Message);
                    log.LogCritical("Inner Exception Stack Trace: " + e.InnerException.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
 public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string connectionString = "Azuresqlconnectionstring";
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
              options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, connectionString));
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]